# How to make proxy server for firefox with linux iptables

Tags: linux, proxy, iptables

I want to use the proxy options in firefox to forward all my connections and network packets to a proxy server (Linux-VM) that will then forward the packets to the real router.

The VM is connected to the router with wifi adapter. The Host machine has wifi adapter as well but i want to forward all its packets that firefox sends to the VM (proxy server)

I am new to this, and i wanted to know how to do this with iptables.

Thanks in advance.